# How to get list of all domains in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, dns

Can anyone please help me to get all the domains in Active Directory. I have tried many times, but all the programs are listing only the current working domain.

How can I do this?

Comment: I bookmarked this link the other day. It offers an approach to to doingthis using LDAP queries. Should be adaptable to ADSI. http://itchanged.com/FindingAllDomainsInAnActiveDirectoryForest.html

Answer (score 10):

```
Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "yourDomain", "username", "password"));

Forest forest = domain.Forest;

DomainCollection domains = forest.Domains;
```

The above uses the System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace.  It'll give you a domain collection containing all the domains that are in the same forest as your given domain.

Answer (score 5):

I had some issues getting [LeeMobile's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/324416/1574221) to work in my case bacause it was trying to find my application's current domain context while running forest.Domains.  I was able to get around it by doing something like this.

```
Forest forest = Forest.GetForest(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest, "yourForestDomain", "username", "password"));
DomainCollection domains = forest.Domains;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using DirectorySearcher you can connect and read the structure of one Active Directory, including the structure (organization units, groups, users, computers, domain controllers). In order to connect to a different domain, you would need credentials of that other domain. We had problems in connecting to another domain from a machine that belongs to a different domain than the target one. I'm also curious if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains

```
var domains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.Cast<Domain>();
foreach (var domain in domains)
{
    Console.WriteLine(domain.Name);
}
```