# c# Howto enumerate DCs in a different domain

Tags: c#, domaincontroller

I would like to enumerate all DCs in a domain (where current user nor computer are member of, and also not in the same forest).

I found this nice method

```
Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
foreach (DomainController dc in domain.DomainControllers)
   ...
```

However, I could not figure out how to do a remote connect with to
get the right domain context.

Connecting via

```
DirectoryEntry child = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + server + "/" + objectDn, userName, password);
```

works well. But I have no Idea how to get this together.

Comment: solution already articulated in SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323608/how-to-get-list-of-all-domains-in-active-directory-using-c-sharp Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "yourDomain", "username", "password"));

Comment: Almost. But this does not allow to pass a IP-Address to where the request should be executed! It would require a Domain within the same Forest.

Comment: just change the type to directoryserver, sorry if I am missing the point of the question System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext dc = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, "<ipaddress here>", "your username", "pwd");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
```

...
....

```
DirectoryContext dc = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, "ip", "user", "pwd"); //change parameters here
Forest forest = Forest.GetForest(dc);    
Console.WriteLine(forest.Domains.Count);
```

the above works for me (gives the correct domain count)

I am testing with a network admin account obviously. Hope this helps

Comment: Works great, thanks. I modified it slightly to get the domain straigt out of the domaincontext instead the forest first.